# Using setTimeout with a function that is using .animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

My function that uses `.animate` is working nicely but I'm trying to add in a setTimeout (probably 2-3 seconds) and not making much progress.

Below is the code for the animation.

```
tt = $('#tickertext');
tt.append('<pre>' + 'Paolo Nutini: New Shoes');
console.log('width ' + tt.width());
w = parseInt(tt.width());
tt.animate({
  left: w * -1
}, w * 10, 'linear', backToStart);
$('#ticker').css('width', '155px').css('visibility', 'visible');
$('#tickerholder').css('width', '155px');

function backToStart() {
  tt.animate({
      left: 155 
  }, 1)
  .animate({
      left: w * -1
  }, (w + 155) * 10, 'linear', backToStart);
}
```

Now below shouldn't I be able to do something like:

```
setTimeout("backToStart", 3000);
```

What exactly am I missing here? The above is having no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like the method is in a closure scope, so try

```
setTimeout(backToStart, 3000);
```

even the string parameter is wrong because in that case you need to invoke the function like `setTimeout("backToStart()", 3000);`, but then the method `backToStart` must be in the global scope

Comment: Yeah tried that earlier, no luck though. Maybe define `backToStart()` WITHIN a setTimeout function?

Comment: @DnfD can you provide some more context to the script like where it is and rest of the surrounding code

Comment: This answer should work.  If it doesn't then you're missing something important from the code you've shown us.

Comment: @ArunPJohny What exactly do you mean here with "closure scope". I know "closure" a bit and "scope" yes, but I cannot figure anything in the code that matches both of them!?! Help!! :D

Comment: @dollarvar if the given code bit including the `backToStart` function is wrapped inside another function (like a dom ready handler or any other function) then the function `backToStart` will be available inside the wrapping function only

Comment: @ArunPJohny Ah, ok, if, yes. I am just reading up on that nasty bit of `setTimeout("")` is evaluating the string and the difference to `setTimeout()` in scope.

Comment: @dollarvar sorry I didn't get you

Comment: @ArunPJohny Well, ok, I still struggle to get a reference for the scope differences of `setTimeout('')` and `setTimeout()` but I clearly understood there is one.

Comment: when you use `setTimeout('')` the statements passed as the string evaluated against the global scope... ie if you call a method here the method must be present in the global scope... in case of passing an actual function reference then the function will called irrespective of in which scope it is defined

Comment: @dollarvar http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Y5Q6K/1/ - works http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Y5Q6K/2/ - throws an error saying `callme` is not a function http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Y5Q6K/3/ - works

Comment: @ArunPJohny Are there other methods who do that?

Comment: @dollarvar to do what?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46716/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-dollarvar)

Comment: Just ended up setting var backToStart = function() {....} and all worked well with `setTimeout`. Gave you an upvote @ArunPJohny as you were essentially right.